# Why Called "Bar Mitzva"

Tags: words, bar-bas-bat-mitzvah

Why is it called Bar MITZVA wouldnt it seem more correct to be called Bar MITZVOS? One might suggest that it refers to being a "Metzuva" I dint think thats correct if so, it should be a bar METZUVA.

Comment: Bar here means "son of", or better yet, "person of." "Person of obligation." Not "obligated person." You're thinking like in English, noun+adjective; Hebrew is good at possessives, and uses them frequently. (Much better to say *handasat chashmal* than *handasa chashmalit*; "engineering of electricity", not "electrical engineering.") "Bar Mitzvah" is the same construction as, for instance, "ben Ir", "person of a city." ("Yosei ben Yoezer Ish Tzereida"; not "Ish HaTzereidi")